# Can I use two different substitutions for the same integral? (Not double substitutions)

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Let's say,

$\int\frac{x+11}{x^2+8x+15}dx = \int\frac{x+4}{x^2+8x+15}dx+\int\frac{7}{(x+3)(x+5)}dx$

So can I use, for example,

$u = x^2+8x+15$ for $\frac{x+4}{x^2+8x+15}$

**and**

$v=x+3$ for $\frac{7}{(x+3)(x+5)}$

It's like I'm solving them separately with different substitutions although they are actually parts of the bigger equation. Is this possible or do I have to stick with the same substitution under the same equation?

I know about the double substitution method but I just want to explore more ways to tackle such questions.

Comment: After you separated the integral into a sum of two integrals you can then evaluate them separately with different substitutions. Just make sure to return back to $x$ after evaluation of the integrals so you can add the results

Answer (score 0):

Better is to write
$$\frac{x+11}{x^2+8x+15}=\frac{4}{x+3}-\frac{3}{x+5}$$

Comment: Exactly what crossed my mind! Why not just use partial fractions?

Comment: I know about partial fractions as well. Like I said, I'm just exploring ways to solve it and want to know if it's possible. :)